# How To Make A For Loop Wait For User Input?

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, doevents

I have a `for` loop that goes to a site and posts to its forms. For every item in the `listbox` I want it to wait for the user to fill out the data to the site, then move. The key point here is 'wait'.

So my question is: is it possible to make a `for` loop to wait for user input?

This is the `for` loop I am working in order to load the data to the forms:

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Welcome"))
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox4.Items.Count; i++ )
    {

        listBox4.SetSelected(i, true);
        listBox5.SetSelected(i, true);
        //coded to submit to form

        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

This is the code to click submit on the site:

```
Application.DoEvents();
foreach (HtmlElement webpageelement in allelements)
{

     if (webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") == "Submit")
     {
         webpageelement.InvokeMember("click");
         Application.DoEvents();

     }

 }
```

I've also tried making a `for` loop without the code in it to make it go on. For ex: i++ and make an `if` statement to make it go on but that lagged my interface.

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Please explain better what you are doing and what you wanna do.

Comment: @Otiel Alright. I have a listbox. In the listbox I can add items to it. For each item in the listbox my program goes to the site and fills predefined information to it. I want the program to wait for the user to fill out the captcha and them clicking the submit button on my interface before the for loop moves down to the next item in the list

Comment: Then use the solution proposed by @HansPassant. Open a new form containing your browser using `Form.ShowDialog()` in your `for` loop, and close this form when the user clicks on your `Submit` button. Your `for` loop will be paused until the user clicks on `Submit`.

Comment: But what if there will be several items in the listbox. Would opening and closing each and everytime be a good solution for the user and for the computer?

Comment: Also, I was asking around on another forum and someone recommended using a do while loop. Would this be a viable solution if I incorporate it with a for loop or should I stick with Form.ShowDialog?

Comment: And I dont want to use Form.ShowDialog cause I want to keep everything on one form :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good solution to do a `for` or a `while` loop to wait for user input. **Don't do that.** Your program will be constantly working while waiting for the condition to get it out of the loop. Instead, you should find a solution using events or else.

If you don't want to use the `Form.ShowDialog()` solution proposed in your question comments, you could come up with something like that:

Have a global variable that holds the index of the listBox item we are working on:

```
int currentItemIndex;
```

Add a `Click` event on your `Submit` button. When the user clicks on `Submit`, it calls the method that will process the next `listBox` item:

```
private void buttonSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Process next listBox item
    ProcessNextItem();
}
```

The method that processes the next `listBox` item:

```
private void ProcessNextItem() {
    currentItemIndex += 1;
    if (currentItemIndex >= listBox.Items.Count) {
        // We have gone through all listBox items

        // Do nothing
    } else {
        // Fill predefined information to the website
        website.SomeField = listBox.Items[currentItemIndex].SomeField; // Whatever you do to fill predefined information
}
```

And call a method at the start (the user doesn't click on `Submit` before the first `listBox` item is processed):

```
private void Start() {
    currentItemIndex = -1;
    ProcessNextItem();
}
```